# Blazor Server .NET 6: redirecting to login page causes infinite reentering of MainLayout page

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I want the user, after registering, to be redirected to a demographics page where he/she fills in additional information and preferences, before being admitted to the site.  After completing the standard registration (username, password), the user defaults to the role of Initializing and is redirected to MembershipPage (which works).

MainLayout.razor:

```
\[CascadingParameter\] protected Task\<AuthenticationState\> AuthState { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var user = (await AuthState).User;

    if (user == null || user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/Identity/Account/Login", true);
    }
    else if (user!.IsInRole("Initializing"))
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/MembershipPage", true);
    }
}
```

MembershipPage:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
    if (context == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var authstate = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    if (authstate == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    User = authstate.User;
    Id = appData.UserId;
    currentUser = context.User.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == int.Parse(Id)); 
}
```

However, it keeps re-entering MainLayout's OnInitializedAsync method, causing "infinite refreshing" of the membership page.  I believe the cause has something to do with the page lifecycle or async methods.  Does anyone have an explanation or suspicion?

Comment: If anyone has any better recommendations for accomplishing this goal, please add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using `MainLayout` as the Layout for your membership page. And force reloading that page in your `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(string path, bool forceReload)` method will reload `MainLayout`.

Add a new Layout for your membership page and use that as the layout, or remove the force reload boolean on your `NavigateTo` method.

Answer (score 1):

This line in MainLayout

```cs
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/MembershipPage", true);
```

causes the SPA to loop because every time you route (try to navigate to MembershipPage) you reload the Layout page.  You never get beyond trying to load the Layout (unless MembershipPage uses a different Layout).

Do your user redirect in `App.razor` and don't force a reload:

```cs
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/MembershipPage", false);
```